# ImmutableList is being edited by the framework

Tags: collections, .net-6.0, immutablelist

I have a method, GetItemCode, which is passed a barcode string and returns an StkBarcode object.

GetItemCode is a method in Class2.  It has an ImmutableList of reference data (called listStkBarcodes, in the code block) that it looks through for a matching barcode. The problem is that listStkBarcodes is getting edited by actions in a different class.

```
private ImmutableList<StkBarcode> listStkBarcodes;
```

The code never edits that ^ list, listStkBarcodes.

Here are the EF Frameworks in the solution:

[image]

Once GetItemCode returns the matching StkBarcode (which has an ItemCode property) to the calling method, the code sometimes edits that ItemCode. That editing is done in Class1.

Here is how the results from GetItemCode are handled in the calling method.

```
 StkBarcode objStkBc = await helper.GetItemCode(strBarcode, TheShippers, ShipperMfCodesList);
```

The value of objStkBc.ItemCode is what the logic sometimes edits.  To me that object, objStkBc, is completely independent of the ImmutableList of reference data in Class2.

The next time GetItemCode is passed the same barcode, the method finds the matching StkBarcode in listStkBarcodes, but this time the corresponding ItemCode, has the edited value of ItemCode.  - the value that the method in Class1 gave it.

So the ImmutableList got edited.

Here is how the ImmutableList gets populated in Class2:

```
public async Task<ImmutableList<StkBarcode>> GetReadOnlyStkBarcodes()
{
    ImmutableList<StkBarcode> TheList = ImmutableList.Create<StkBarcode>();
    List<StkBarcode> theList = await _context.StkBarcodes.Where(b => b.ItemCode != null
                   && b.Barcode != null).ToListAsync();
    TheList = theList.ToImmutableList();
    return TheList;
}
```

Regarding the ToImmutableList method above:  I don't see it in the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=net-6.0), however if I do F12 on it (in Visual Studio) it is there in the System.Collections.Immutable namespace.

Here is the StkBarcode class, in case this helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MainModels.MainModels
{
    public partial class StkBarcode
    {
        public StkBarcode()
        {
            ScannedItems = new HashSet<ScannedItem>();
        }
        public StkBarcode(string itemCode, string custCode)
        {
            ItemCode = itemCode;
            CustCode = custCode;
            BarcodeId = 0;
            Count = 0; DefaultLock = false; RequireLotCode = false; CreatedDatetime = DateTime.Now;
            ScannedItems = new HashSet<ScannedItem>();
        }
        public int BarcodeId { get; set; }
        public string? Barcode { get; set; }
        public string? ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string? CustCode { get; set; }
        public short? MobileDeviceId { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public int? CreateBy { get; set; }
        public string? OldItemCode { get; set; }
        public bool? IsSubstitute { get; set; }
        public bool DefaultLock { get; set; }
        public bool RequireLotCode { get; set; }
        public bool LotCode { get; set; }
        public bool? Deleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDatetime { get; set; }
        public byte[]? RowVersion { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<ScannedItem>? ScannedItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need the ImmutableList, listStkBarcodes, to never get edited.  Ideas?

Comment: Not sure, but is that object instance you insert into the ImmutableList read by EF? In this case beware of caching (are you using the same DbContext instances for different calls?). You might get the same instance for different calls and that might cause concurrent modifications to that instance.  As a side node, C# namespaces, have nothing to do with all of this (if you meant them by saying "namespace" above).

Comment: @Christian.K   Thanks tons for the feedback.  I have made edits to the post to clarify the flow.  You wrote,  "object instance you insert into the ImmutableList"  the code never inserts anything into that list once it is initially populated.  Yes, I am using EF and yes, I am using the same Db Context for all of this.  In the post I write, "To me that object, objStkBc, is completely independent of the ImmutableList of reference data in Class2."  but maybe I am wrong about that?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, with "inserting" I meant "initialy populated", which inserts as well, just you can never change it later ;-). "So the ImmutableList got edited." - no that is not the case. The object instance *inside* the list has been edited. You have to find out why. Sorry, I have no other way to say this. This might sound like nitpicking on wording, but is important to understand the real issue here.

Comment: @Christian.K  I don't feel at all that you are nitpicking.  Its all about the details.  : - )   I like, "you have to find out why"  - that is exactly my problem.  : - )   I am posting the workaround that I ended up using.  Its is hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Immutable collections cannot be modified. However, the *items* they contain may be modified. It sounds like you have two different parts of the code that are accessing the same `StkBarcode` instance concurrently.

The only way to fix this is to manage the concurrent access of the `StkBarcode` instance. Either make that type immutable, or protect it with a `lock`.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see how the StkBarcode that the code edits is the same instance that is in the ImmutableList.  The two are in different namespaces/classes.  I am trying to point this out above with "The calling method is in a different namespace from the GetItemCode method."  The object that I am editing is created within its namespace from the results of the method call to the other namespace, Like:  StkBarcode ObjectToBeEdited = OtherNamespace.GetTheObjToBeEdited();  << that object is from the ImmutableList.  Ideas>  Thanks again.

Comment: @pdschuller: please post a minimal, reproducible example so others can observe exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thank you again sir.  I have made edits in the post that I think clarify the flow.  I have added pseudo class names, which I think help alot.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround I ended up with.

1. I created a new type that is identical to StkBarcode, lets call it
   StkBarcodeCopy
2. I put the reference data that had been going to listStkBarcodes in a
   list of that new type, List
3. the code searches in ListStkBarcodeCopy for the matching item it wants
4. if the code finds a matching item we convert the StkBarcodeCopy item
   to a StkBarcode
5. then the code does its thing with THAT object
6. the code edits the object as I describe above, but the reference
   data never gets edited